# Can phala be experienced too often?

Tags: nirvana, stages-of-the-path

If a person enters phala(nibbana) too frequently can they develop a tolerance to the peacefulness of it?

Answer (score 3):

There's no question of tolerance or intolerance. Nibbana is non-experiential(Avedeita) peace.

Answer (score 1):

Developing tolerance for anything means that there is change, transformation, conditionality and causation present.

Nibbana is unchanging, unconditioned and uncaused so developing tolerance would not be possible.

Tolerance is a phenomena that belongs to conditioned reality.